# Convert www. https/http into <a tag in text PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to convert all urls inside text into links with `<a` tag, I've done that buy I faced a problem and its when I enter any tag with src it changes into `<a` tag also I will give u some example about what Im trying to say:
Let's say I want to convert this into urls links

```
Visit www.google.com or http://google.com <img src="http://mysite/image.jpg">
```

So `www.google.com` and `http://google.com` become '' but the problem `<img src="http://mysite/image.jpg">` also become

```
<img src="<a href="http://mysite/image.jpg"></a>">
```

my php `preg_replace` code is :

```html
$find=array('`((?:https?|ftp)://\S+[[:alnum:]]/?)`si','`((?<!//)(www\.\S+[[:alnum:]]/?))`si', '`((?<!//)([a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.\S+[[:alnum:]]/?))`si');
$replace=array('<a href="$1" target="_blank" class="comment_textLink">$1</a>','<a href="http://$1"    target="_blank" class="comment_textLink">$1</a>' ,'<a href="mailto://$1" class="comment_textLink">$1</a>');
$string = preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
```

I've tried to add space before link of url which it will convert but it caused problem when I put a link on the first of text. How can I salve this thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `(^|\s)`at the beginning of your Regex to specify that it's either a beginning of a string, or a space.

Therefore, it'll only look for links that are at the beginning of a string, or has a space before to replace them with your a tags.